# Tap on Widget To Open App

Tags: java, android, listview, widget, touch

I have been trying to open my app through tapping on the widget for weeks but nothing seems to work. I think something about my code makes my situation different of something. My widget is just a list with tasks on it. I will just post entire classes so people can see what is going on.

Could someone please help me with this?

ListProvider:

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private ArrayList<ListObject> listObjectList = new ArrayList<ListObject>();
    private Context context = null;
    private TinyDB tinyDB;

    private ArrayList<Integer> checkedPositions = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        populateWidget();
    }

    private void populateWidget() {
        if(MainActivity.user != null) {

            checkedPositions.clear();

            for(int i = 0; i < MainActivity.user.getTaskLists().size(); i++){
                TaskList taskList = MainActivity.user.getTaskLists().get(i);

                listObjectList.add(new ListTitle(taskList.getName()));

                for (int j = 0; j < taskList.getTasks().size(); j++) {
                    ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
                    listItem.text = taskList.getTasks().get(j).getTitle();
                    listObjectList.add(listItem);

                    if(taskList.getTasks().get(j).isChecked()){
                        //if task is checked, add to checked list
                        checkedPositions.add(listObjectList.size() - 1);
                    }
                }

                listObjectList.add(new ListItem(" "));
            }
        }else{
            loadLastSavedList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listObjectList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*
     *Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View
     *we return RemoteViews
     *
     */
    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_item);

        ListObject listObject = listObjectList.get(position);

        //get whether item is a item or title
        if(listObject.getClass().equals(ListItem.class)) {
            //list item
            ListItem listItem = (ListItem) listObject;
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "");
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, listItem.text);
        }else{
            //list title
            ListTitle listTitle = (ListTitle) listObject;
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "");
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, listTitle.title);
        }

        //text size
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());

        String textSize = SP.getString(context.getString(R.string.widget_pref_key_text_size), context.getString(R.string.medium));
        System.out.println(textSize);
        if (textSize.equals(context.getString(R.string.small))) {
            //small
            remoteView.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.text, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
            remoteView.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.title, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        } else if (textSize.equals(context.getString(R.string.large))) {
            //large
            remoteView.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.text, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
            remoteView.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.title, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
        } else {
            //medium, default
            remoteView.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.text, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
            remoteView.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.title, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        }

        //strikethrough if checked
        if(checkedPositions.contains(position)){
            remoteView.setInt(R.id.text, "setPaintFlags", Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }else{
            remoteView.setInt(R.id.text, "setPaintFlags", (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) & Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }


        return remoteView;
    }


    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        loadLastSavedList();
    }

    private void loadLastSavedList() {
        //load up saved items
        tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
        ArrayList<String> strings = tinyDB.getListString(context.getString(R.string.saved_key));
        System.out.println(strings.size());

        //full up listItems
        for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            if(i == 0){
                //first object, title
                listObjectList.add(new ListTitle(strings.get(i)));
            }else if(strings.get(i - 1).equals(" ")){
                //title
                listObjectList.add(new ListTitle(strings.get(i)));
            }else{
                //list item
                listObjectList.add(new ListItem(strings.get(i)));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        listObjectList.clear();
        populateWidget();

        //save list items
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ListObject listObject: listObjectList){
            if(listObject.getClass().equals(ListItem.class)) {
                //list item
                ListItem listItem = (ListItem) listObject;
                strings.add(listItem.text);
            }else{
                //list title
                ListTitle listTitle = (ListTitle) listObject;
                strings.add(listTitle.title);
            }
        }

        tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
        tinyDB.putListString(context.getString(R.string.saved_key), strings);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

}
```

WidgetProvider:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    /**
     * this method is called every 30 mins as specified on widgetinfo.xml
     * this method is also called on every phone reboot
     **/
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager
            appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

/*int[] appWidgetIds holds ids of multiple instance
 * of your widget
 * meaning you are placing more than one widgets on
 * your homescreen*/
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],
                    remoteViews);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context,
                                             int appWidgetId) {

        //which layout to show on widget
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        //setting a unique Uri to the intent
        //don't know its purpose to me right now
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(
                svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //setting adapter to listview of the widget
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
                svcIntent);
        //setting an empty view in case of no data
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);

        return remoteViews;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any code that tells Android that you are expecting to do anything when the user clicks on a list item.

In `getViewAt()`, you need to create an `Intent`, populate it with extras (e.g., to identify the data associated with this list row), and call `setOnClickFillInIntent()` on the `RemoteViews` that is supposed to respond to the click event.

Then, in `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider`, you need to call `setPendingIntentTemplate()` on the `RemoteViews` that holds your `ListView` (or `StackView` or whatever you are using), where this `PendingIntent` wraps an `Intent` to be filled in and invoked when the user taps on an item in that `ListView`.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget) demonstrates this, by creating an app widget that shows a list of 25 Latin words and responding to clicks on each of them.

Comment: This works but I would like it so if you press anywhere on the widget it will open. This makes it so you have to press on a list item.

Comment: @Jared: AFAIK, if you are presenting a `ListView` in an app widget, the user will expect that tapping on a list item will bring up something specific for that list item. In your case, it would display an activity with details of the task that the user clicked on. After all, this is how scrolling lists work everywhere else in Android: click on an item and something happens relevant to that specific item. That being said, you can try calling `setOnClickPendingIntent()` on the `RemoteViews`, passing in the ID of the `ListView`.

Comment: setPendingIntentTemplate() FTW! Thank you so much. 
I pasted so many other SO threads that didn't work before I got here.